# Is simulink part of Matlab product or a standalone product by itself?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am not really sure on this one. I wanted to know simulink is part of matlab software or if it is a product that can be bought and installed  by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.mathworks.com/products/availability/) the relevant product dependency documentation. If you scroll down the list to *Simulink*, it states

> Simulink
>
> ```
> Requires MATLAB
> Requires Fixed-Point Designer for simulating fixed-point data types
> Some features require the use of a C Compiler. ...
> ```

Simulink cannot be run as standalone software, it requires MATLAB to be installed.

Comment: I think technically it's a toolbox, isn't it? TMW just doesn't use the term in this case.

Comment: @A.Donda I suppose everything in that list is technically a toolbox, except for MATLAB itself.